# AS3 TimerEvents

Tags: actionscript-3, action

i have a problem because action script 3.0 Timer Events.i have big action script project, actually until now, everything is very good.But this day i was make a control and i find a problem.Problem is very big.

That project have a much different screen, and all screen is connect each other.all screen have a sound.Some screen have a several sound.if the sound a single;we import this a Urlloader.if the sound number a more;we import this timerevent + urlloader.Now, we walk around screen, if we go to main screen our sound object continues to play.this sound object must never will plays. i hope this been descriptive.Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SoundChannel class for this, look here: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/ (Section 4 - Stopping a Sound)

Answer (score 0):

I think u should consider some class or library handling all the sounds playing, it's easier to separate such functionality to a single class. U can then simply say to that class to stop playing all the sounds, or actualy playing sound.

This is not the best, but it will work fine: https://github.com/treefortress/SoundAS
They have decent docs too.